# Testing retina mod rewrite under Windows

Tags: mobile, emulation, retina-display

I want to serve retina images to devices with high resolution displays. I have no smartphone, so I downloaded Opera Mobile Simulator. It works on this site: http://tekshrek.de/retina/ but not on mine.

I dont know, how they did it, but I think it is made with JS or CSS. For my site it doesn't work. But I dont know, if its my fault, or if the .htaccess method doesn't work with Opera Mobile Simulator.

What I need is:

A: Further information on Opera Mobile Simulator (If it is possible to test the mod rewrite in it)

or

B: An Alternative emulator / Test method

or at least

C: A site that uses mod rewrite, so I can test it. (It should have images with watermarks for retina size, so I'm shure, what I look at)

and

D: Any other advice, in how to simulate retina displays